# How to update Html control without runat="server"

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, visual-studio

I have an Html image which I need to update dynamically but without runat="server" my code behind cannot see it.

```
<img name="MDI" id="detailimg" src="" alt="blankimage.jpg" />
```

I can access it using Page.Request.Form["MDI"]; but not update it

I need to load the src image at run time so can someone please tell me how I can update the control in my code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do with inline syntax like below

```
<img name="MDI" id="detailimg" src="<%= getImageSource() %>" alt="blankimage.jpg" />
```

In codebehind

```
public string getImageSource()
{
   return "urlpath/img.jpeg";
}
```

More about [`Inline Syntax`](http://weblogs.asp.net/ahmedmoosa/archive/2010/10/06/embedded-code-and-inline-server-tags.aspx)

Comment: I believe you need to use the `<%= %>` syntax

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update via code behind, you have to set `runat="server"`

If inline is fine, use `src="<%= something%>`

Otherwise use javascript for example

Answer (score 0):

as you know if you want to access an element/control from code behind,you should set runat="server" but there is 2 other ways to set properties from code behind

1. use inline syntax as other guys shows (<%= YourVoidToGetImgSrc %>
2. use Ajax and get value from code behind in your html page.